# Tesseract OCR - определение строк длиной меньше 3 (как я понимаю они улетают в шум, но так ли это?)

Tags: c#, изображения, распознавание-символов, tesseract

Уже который день мучаюсь с вопросом, как же вытащить символы и слова длиной меньше 3 из изображения?

**Вот примеры изображений с которыми всё отлично распознается:**
[image: Получается]
[image: Получается]

**А вот с этими изображениями нет:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мой код:

```
public class OcrService
{
    private Tesseract.TesseractEngine _tesseractEngine { get; set; }
    public OcrService(string language = "rus+eng")
    {
        string tessdataPath = Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "tessdata");
        _tesseractEngine = new TesseractEngine(tessdataPath, language, engineMode.Default, "--psm 8");
    }

    public string GetAllTextFromImage(string path, Rect? region = null)
    {
        Pix pix = Pix.LoadFromFile(path);
        Tesseract.Page page;
        if (region != null)
            page = this._tesseractEngine.Process(pix, region.Value, null);
        else
            page = this._tesseractEngine.Process(pix);
        string str = page.GetText();
        pix.Dispose();
        return str;
    }
```

Подскажите, может мне что-то необходимо почитать, изучить, попробовать? Куда копать и где рыть, не пойму. Попробовал использовать tesseract 3.0, всё точно также.
Заранее спасибо за содействие :)

Answer (score 0):

Можно установить сегментацию в один символ, `setPageSegMode(TessBaseAPI.PSM_SINGLE_CHAR);` но возможно это следует делать как fallback, потому как это может привести к разделению строки на несколько

Comment: К сожалению psm 10 не решает этой проблемы

Comment: @Anilen 11, 12? Скорее всего мешает рамка таблицы. Возможно нужен еще какой-то инструмент для поиска "островков" текста

Comment: Что вы подразумеваете под поиском "островков" текста? Что-то на подобии OpenCV?

Comment: Возможно. У тессеракта есть PSM режимы PSM_SPARSE_TEXT\PSM_SPARSE_TEXT_OSD но это тоже может быть недостаточным.